# Server side react router onEnter handling, transition.redirect is not a function

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-router

for my isomorphic application, i'm usign react router (**2.0.1**) and i need to handle authentication, so i used the **onEnter** hook , according to the documentation api. I need to handle authentication but getting

> TypeError: transition.redirect is not a function

*routes.jsx file*

```
**/**
 *
 * @param next
 * @param transition
 * @param callback
 */
function  requireAuth  (next, transition, callback) {
    if (!window.user){
        transition.abort();
        transition.redirect ({
            pathname: '/login',
            state: { nextPathname: next.location.pathname }
        }, transition);
    }
    else {
        callback(null, transition);
    }
}**



<Router history={history} onUpdate={onUpdate} onEnter={requireAuth}>
            <Route path="/rt/" component={RealTime}/>
            <Route path="/" component={Blank}/>
            {devRoutes}

 </Router>
```

*server.js file*

```
app.get('*', function(req, res, next) {
 Router.run(routes(), location, function(e, i, t) {
      var str = React.renderToString(
                  React.createElement(Router, i));
      res.send (str)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no **transition.redirect** function,  i need to modify the **transition redirectInfo**  object in the onEnter transition hook using **transition.to** and then verfiy in the main server handler function.

```
/**
 *
 * @param next
 * @param transition
 * @param callback
 */
function  requireAuth  (next, transition, callback) {
    var loginPath = '/account/login/' ;
    if (!window.user && !(next.location.pathname === loginPath)){
        transition.abort();
        transition.to(loginPath, null, {
            //data: req.body,
            //errors: res.body
        })
    }
    callback()
}
```

The redirection is not handled on **onEnter** hook but in the main server get handler.

```
app.get('*', function(req, res, next) {
 Router.run(routes(), location, function(e, i, transition) {
     // **********************************************
     //  handling redirection info 
     if (transition.isCancelled) {
        console.log ('transition cancelled');
        return res.redirect(302, transition.redirectInfo.pathname);
      }
     // ********************************************************
      var str = React.renderToString(
                  React.createElement(Router, i));
      res.send (str)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your requireAuth should look  like this

```
function  requireAuth  (next, transition, callback) {
    if (!window.user){
        transition({
            pathname: '/login',
            state: { nextPathname: next.location.pathname }
        });
    }
    else {
        callback();
    }
}
```

you can see [here](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/examples/auth-flow/app.js#L120) that transition doesn't call methods and if 'if' statement fails you just pass empty callback to continue to the page

Comment: thanx, but i'm using react 2.0.1 and seems not works ** transition is not a function**